# Override virtual method from abstract class

Tags: c++, inheritance, observer-pattern

I need to test notifying system based on observer pattern. Here is my `Observer` class:

```
template <typename DataType>
class Subject;

template <typename DataType>
class Observer {
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}
    virtual void receive(Subject<DataType> *subject) = 0;
};
```

`DataType` is tparam data. `receive()` will receive and process the message called by `Subject` when it is updated. `Subject` is a pointer to the subject from which the data came.

Here is a part of `Subject` class with `attach()` method:

```
template <typename DataType>
class Subject {
public:
    typedef Observer<DataType> SameDataObserver;

    Subject():
        dataPtr_(NULL),
        observers_() {
    }

    void attach(SameDataObserver *observerPtr) {
        assert(observerPtr != NULL);
        observers_.pushBack(observerPtr);
    }
...
private:
...
};
```

So, I wrote an inheritor of the `Observer` abstract class like this. I guess here I need to define only the `receive()` method:

```
class TestObserver : Observer<IdString> {
    virtual void receive(Subject<DataType> *subject) override {};
};
```

`IdString` is `typedef String<64> IdString;`.

In my `main()` function, I do this:

```
const IdString data = "button pressed";
Subject<IdString> subject;
TestObserver<IdString> testObserver;
subject.attach(&testObserver);
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
[build] /home/a.wise/Downloads/test_notifying_system/test_notifying_system.cpp:20:32: error: no matching function for call to ‘Subject<String<64> >::attach(TestObserver<String<64> >&)’
[build]      subject.attach(testObserver);
[build]                                 ^
[build] In file included from /home/a.wise/Downloads/test_notifying_system/test_notifying_system.cpp:7:0:
[build] /home/a.wise/Downloads/test_notifying_system/src/notifying_system/subject.h:29:10: note: candidate: void Subject<DataType>::attach(Subject<DataType>::SameDataObserver*) [with DataType = String<64>; Subject<DataType>::SameDataObserver = Observer<String<64> >]
[build]      void attach(SameDataObserver *observerPtr) {
[build]           ^~~~~~
```

Comment: The error mentions the line `subject.attach(testObserver);` but your code has `subject.attach(&testObserver);`, which is correct. Are you compiling the right code? Is this used it multiple places and you didn't change it everywhere?

Comment: In `class TestObserver : Observer<IdString> { void receive(wise::Subject<DataType> *subject) override {}; };` You would need to replace `DataType` with `IdString`.

Comment: @Kevin I haven't changed the code and it hasn't been used anywhere, I need to check that everything works as it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I missed public word, right code:

```
template <typename DataType>
class TestObserver : public Observer<IdString> {
    public:
    virtual void receive(Subject<DataType> *subject) override {};
};
```

After that it compiles